# Bootstrap : dropdown button doesn't work anymore

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I was checking one of my website when I discovered that my dropdown menus do not work anymore (don't want to collapse).

It was working perfectly some months ago. I am building this website using bootstrap and vue (I suspect something went wrong with upgrading maybe).

Here is part of my code

```html
<p><button v-on:click="contacts = !contacts" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle"   data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" v-scroll-to="'#con'">Infos contact </button></p>
                <div class="contacts text-left" v-if="contacts" id="con">
                    <p><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> 14, rue xxx, 92270 Bois Colombes</p>
                    <p><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i><a href="http://www.linkedin.com/in/xxx"> www.linkedin.com/in/xxx</a></p>
                    <p><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i><a href="xxx.xxx@yahoo.fr"> xx.xx@yahoo.fr</a></p>
                    <p><i class="fa fa-phone"></i> 06 xx xx xx xx</p>
                </div>
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide a [mre]. Please also see [What should I keep out of my posts and titles?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/131009/997587)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well finally i found out the reason why it doesn't work : It was in fact upgrading issue . I add this `<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" > <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" ></script> <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Atwg2Pkwv9vp0ygtn1JAojH0nYbwNJLPhwyoVbhoPwBhjQPR5VtM2+xf0Uwh9KtT" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>` instead of my bootswatch call since there are some uncompatibilities with Vue.js and i used this `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>` to call Vue.js instead of `<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script> <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-scrollto"></script>` that seems to be overdated for Vue call . Hope it will help some other members .

Answer (score 0):

You use a v-on:click but why not use the standard code from dropdown from [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/dropdowns/)

You can do it like this:

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <a class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
    Info contact
  </a>

  <div class="dropdown-menu">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">14, rue xxx, 92270 Bois Colombes</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="http://www.linkedin.com/in/xxx">www.linkedin.com/in/xxx</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="xxx.xxx@yahoo.fr">xx.xx@yahoo.fr</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

You just have to add your icons. Also for future reference I would not add your head in your question but instead just the dropdown in the body and specificy your language used in the code block so its easier to read.